# Is this usage for ArrayAdapter in android is right?

Tags: android, onclick

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                setContentView (R.layout.choose);
                       lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.options);
                     String[] lv_arr= new String [] {"Book a Classified Ad","Book a Classified display Ad","Book a display Ad","Page Position Availability", "MIS", "Market Share", "Approval", "Upload Material" };
                    ArrayList<String> Options = new ArrayList<String>();  
                    Options.addAll(Arrays.asList(lv_arr));
                    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.choose, R.id.options);  

                    lv1.setAdapter( listAdapter );      

                                      }
           });
```

The Error it is giving is "The constructor ArrayAdapter(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, int, int) is undefined"

I am complete new in programing so please tell me how to change to the list view from Onclicklistner here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` in

```
ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.choose, R.id.options);
```

refers to a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` class. ArrayAdapter needs a pointer to an object that extends Context (ie an activity, preferably a listactivity).

Comment: Thank you ... understood this... can you show me an example or any link that i can study....

Comment: I need to switch to different view from this DialogInterface

Comment: Are you sure you want to switch to a different view and not start a new activvity? Creating a list like this is pretty unusual